# Packaged products with overal discount Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to implement packaged products.

The requirement is that there are sets of videos and document files which i have to setup in woocommerce.

For e.g

> Package A
>         Video How to do wordpress - 18.00
>         Video Build basic theme - 20.00&
>         PDF wordpress plugins basics - 10.00$

and other packages like Package B, C etc.

I have to provide such a flow that user can purchase the whole package as well as any single product. When he purchases the complete package, I will have to provide them discount too.

I tried the grouped product feature, but that doesn't suit my need, as in grouped product there is a one parent product, and other childs where as in my case, there is no parent product instead they are under a package hood.

If this can be done without any plugin this will be super awesome, but I am open to any ideal plugin suggestion too.

Comment: Check this plugin http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/ it's not free but it does what you are looking for. Also there is no difference between theme code and plugin code (why not use a plugin?) but it's recommended using plugins because it will keep the website logic even when the theme changes.

Comment: yes i've tried this and it helped me. Thanks

Comment: @alexalex "If this can be done without any plugin this will be super awesome," By this i mean within woocommerce defauls.

Comment: I see, well I guess that the plugin uses woocommece as much as possible, I'm happy to hear it works for you and sorry I don't have a free solution...

Comment: lol but i got a nulled script :P

Comment: @alexalex Can you please post it in answer so that i can mark it as completed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is already out there in the form of a premium plugin [Product Bundles](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/) there are for sure ways of getting to the same results on your own but some it needs a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to create a product called 'Package A', which sells for $38, and have seperate products for eadh individual item.